# How to yield results from a nested generator function?

Tags: python, function, nested, generator, yield

I have a function which yields results as it downloads them. For the purposes of this question, lets say I yield a sting once every second but I want a convenience function to wrap my generator:

```
import time

def GeneratorFunction(max_val):
    for i in range(0,5):
        time.sleep(1)
        yield "String %d"%i

def SmallGenerator():
    yield GeneratorFunction(3)

for s in SmallGenerator():
    print s
```

...why doesn't that just print the 5 strings I'm expecting? Instead it appears to return the generator functio:

```
<generator object GeneratorFunction at 0x020649B8>
```

How can I get this to yield the strings as a normal generator function would?

Comment: FYI, in Python 3.3, `yield from GeneratorFunction(3)` will work..

Comment: @DSM: Thanks. Still not quite made the transition to 3+ yet...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Can't believe I missed this; The answer is to simply return the generator function with suitable arguments applied:

```
import time

def GeneratorFunction(max_val):
    for i in range(0,max_val):
        time.sleep(1)
        yield "String %d"%i

def SmallGenerator():
    return GeneratorFunction(3) # <-- note the use of return instead of yield

for s in SmallGenerator():
    print s
```

Comment: unless your function reads: yield GeneratorFunction(3) yield GeneratorFunction(2). In this case a return would not work. Yield From fulfills this requirement.

Comment: but if you are using `return` inside `def SmallGenerator():`, it is not a nested generator function anymore?? or is it??

Answer (score 72):

You may have to use the [new `yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html), available since Python 3.3, known as “[delegated generator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr)”.

If I understood the question correctly, I came to the same issue, and found an answer elsewhere.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
def f():

    def g():

        do_something()
        yield x
        …
        yield y

    do_some_other_thing()
    yield a
    …
    g()  # Was not working.
    yield g()  # Was not what was expected neither; yielded None.
    …
    yield b
```

I now use this instead:

```
yield from g()  # Now it works, it yields x and Y.
```

I got the answer from this page: [Python 3: Using "yield from" in Generators - Part 1 (simeonvisser.com)](http://simeonvisser.com/posts/python-3-using-yield-from-in-generators-part-1.html).

Answer (score 4):

Came here looking for a different form of "nested yield" and finally found the hidden answer. Might not be the best but it works.

I was wanting to yield through a registry tree and here is the solution.

```
        def genKeys(key):
            for value in key.values():
                yield value
            for subkey in key.subkeys():
                print(subkey)
                for x in genKeys(subkey): #this is the trick
                    continue
```

Comment: Looks like this yields the top-level values, and recursively prints subkeys, but doesn't recursively yield anything. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another small example for generating the multiplication table from 1 to 10:

```
class Gen1:

    def __init__(self, gen2):
        self.gen2 = gen2

    def __iter__(self):    
        for a in range(1, 11):    
            for b in self.gen2:
                yield a * b


class Gen2:    

    def __iter__(self):
        for a in range(1, 11):
            yield a


def main():

    gen2 = Gen2()
    gen1 = Gen1(gen2)

    for v in gen1:
        print(v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I came looking for another use of nested yields..

```
list_of_lists = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
]

def iter_all(foo):
    yield foo

    if isinstance(foo, list):
        for i in foo:
            for x in iter_all(i):
                yield x


print([i for i in iter_all(list_of_lists)])
```

output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [1, 2, 3], 1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9], 7, 8, 9]
```